# Can you use primitive types for generic parameters in a class or method?

Tags: java

I am writing a short paper on generics and I have not really used them all that much in Java. I was wondering if a primitive type can be used as a parameter type in a generic variable. I have not been able to get it to compile with a generic parameter that is of a generic type.

Question: I am somewhat not certain as to how generics can handle primitive datatypes. Can someone example how I would have to declare the method different to not have to add a cast to the int type with Integer and if it is possible to use a primitive Java datatype in the class declaration

```
   DDHGeneric<int,int,int,int> t = new DDHGeneric<int,int,int,int>();
```

Is there a way to do this?

The following declaration does not compile either. I do know that from what I know about generics that there is a different between using the primitive data types and a user-defined class.

```
   DDHGeneric<int, int, int, int> temp2 = new  DDHGeneric<int, int, int, int>();
```

Class:

```
public class DDHGeneric<T,K,Bigfoot,Pizza> {
    T a;
    K n;
    Bigfoot u;

    public DDHGeneric() {
    }

    private <rapper> void myMethod(rapper y) {
    int temp = y; <--Errors out on this line as will.
}

    public <Pizza> void myAddition(Pizza a, Pizza b) {
    }

    private <K> void me(K a, K b, K c) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         DDHGeneric<int, Integer, Integer, Integer> temp = new  DDHGeneric<int, Integer, Integer, Integer>();
         temp.myAddition(5, 4);
         temp.a = "Test this string!" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is you cannot.

Comment: You cannot because there is no common representation for primitives.  All objects have a single common representation -- an Object reference pointer -- so the type can be set after the implementation of the generic is compiled.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot.

Oracle gives [an article on this topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html).

to quote:

> When creating a Pair object, you cannot substitute a primitive type for the type parameter K or V:
>
> `Pair<int, char> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');  // compile-time error`
>
> You can substitute only non-primitive types for the type parameters K and V:
>
> `Pair<Integer, Character> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');`

Answer (score 4):

No.

Generics aren't meant to represent primitives.  They're meant to represent objects (as the generic types [all extend `Object` implicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)).

You can use the wrapper variants of the primitive class you want instead to achieve the same effect.

```
 DDHGeneric<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer> t = new DDHGeneric<>();
```

Here is a brief excerpt from [Why Use Generics?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html), found in the Java Trails:

> In a nutshell, generics enable **types** (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods.

Comment: Thank you. Both of these are very good answers. I always have a difficult time deciding on whos answer to accept. Is there any hard and fast rule that people follow for this type of work.

Comment: @DougHauf Nope, just pick an answer. In this case, I'd suggest going with the person who answered first ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generics only take primitive class but not the primitive data type.

For each data type used its corrasponding class for it

`DDHGeneric<int,int,int,int> t = new DDHGeneric<int,int,int,int>();`

can be used as

`DDHGeneric<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer> t = new DDHGeneric<Integer, Integer, Integer, Integer>();`